# Text changed event not firing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, obout

I am using a textbox inside an update panel and there is `textchanged` event for this text box. `textchanged` event is firing first time and showing an alert box that email id  is present. when i giving email id in text box . but after clicking ok button in alert box again i give email id in text box  this time textchanged event not firing.

**HTML**

```
<dt>Email:<span style="color: #FF0000;">*</span></dt>
<dd>
<**asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel8" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <cc1:OboutTextBox ID="txtEmail"   class="input" runat="server" 
            ontextchanged="txtEmail_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></cc1:OboutTextBox>

   </ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtEmail" EventName="TextChanged"  />
 </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>**
</dd>
</dl>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void txtEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        if (txtEmail.Text.Trim() != "")
        {
            string _GlobalDB = Server.MapPath("~//DB//Global.accdb");
            flag = Utility.isEmailExist(txtEmail.Text.Trim(), _GlobalDB);
        }
        if (flag)
        {

           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "MyScript", @"javascript:alert('Email ID Exist ,Please Use another Email ID.')", true);
            txtEmail.Text = "";
            txtEmail.Focus();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you using a custom textbox? Your code show cc1:OboutTextBox instead of asp textbox.

Comment: Try using the regular ASP.net textbox first and iron out any issues that you face. Once the base is set, then use your third party control

Comment: may be because you are using semi colon after alert('Email ID Exist ,Please Use another Email ID.')

Comment: with regular ASP.net textbox it working as expected but issue is with third party control.